# Is it possible to pass arguments to select nodes path?

Tags: vba, excel

Below condition is returning the list of elements under a specific node.

```
Set List = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//page[0]/method")
```

Total page nodes are 3. And I am passing an argument into the path to get particular elements of a node and it is working.

But when I parameterize argument value it is not working.

```
Dim i As integer
i=0
Set List = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//page[i]/method")
```

**Is there any way to pass the arguments in a loop?**

Please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To combine variables with text, you need to use `quotes` and `&`:

```
Dim i As integer
  i=0
Set List = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//page[" & i & "]/method")
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to include a variable and loop it:

```
Dim i As integer
For i = 0 to 10
    Set List = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//page[" & i & "]/method")

    ' Do something with the List

Next
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use helper function:

```
Function FormatString(s As String, ParamArray args())
    Dim x As Integer
    For x = 0 To UBound(args)
        s = Replace$(s, "{" & x & "}", args(x))
    Next
    FormatString = s
End Function
```

Usage:

```
Set List = xmlDoc.SelectNodes(FormatString("//page[{0}]/method", i))
```

Comment: What a complex solution. But good to know other ways to achieve the result.

Comment: The `FormatString` is just a helper, which makes string more readable.

Comment: Thanks Johnny for showing another way to achieve this 